# Represent Infinity in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been building a system that tracks royalties for authors. Say an author's royalty rate is based on sales: 0 - 5000 and they get say, 10 percent. 5001 - 10,000 they get 15 percent. My question, is how to I tell Rails that the final rule should be 10,001 - infinity? Right now, this is represented in a royalty_rules table with lower and upper columns and each royalty_rule belongs_to: contract and each contract :has_many royalty_rules.

I have a similar issue with dates ... I put beginning and end times in the dates, and sometimes, I don't want the contract to have an end date.

Comment: I'm a little confused: are you asking how to check ranges like this in code, or are you asking how to store ranges like this in your database? If the latter, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I was asking about storing them in the database ... MySQL

Comment: You could store only the lower value if your ranges are continuous. 0, 5001, 10,001. Find the rule with the biggest value of 'lower' that's less than or equal to the sales figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Ruby doesn't have constants for `Infinity` or `-Infinity`, it does know about the concepts and you can create them yourself:

```
irb> Numeric::Infinity = 1.0/0
#=> Infinity

irb> range = 10001..Numeric::Infinity
#=> 10001..Infinity

irb> range.include?( 234234234234134134134 )
#=> true
```

**Edit**: *Actually, Ruby 1.9.2 seems to have added `Float::INFINITY`, so if you're on the leading edge you can just use this.*

Comment: Did you mean bleeding edge? :)

Comment: @KARASZI István: 1.9.2 isn't bleeding edge; it's the current stable release version.

Comment: I was commenting on the 'leading edge' phrase, which exists on airplanes AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

Here is small tutorial about using [Infinity in Rails](http://devblog.xing.com/ruby/using-rubys-infinity-in-rails/)

Comment: I'm glad someone posted this. I couldn't remember where I had seen it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest allowing the upper limit columns take NULL in the database. That will map to `nil` in Rails, and is easily tested for, either with `nil?` or with the fact that `nil` is "falsey".